# Sort array of DateTime values and grab the newest DateTime value?

Tags: php, sorting

I have a PHP Array where I can make the key's or values be in this format `10/03/2013 01:45pm`

What my end goal is to sort the array on this DateTime value and then assign the NEWEST value to a variable.

I have been looking at the PHP function `uksort` but I am not sure if that is the solution for this problem and if it is, I am not sure how to sort the array in that manner based on this DateTime value and then grab the newest value.

Any help please?

Comment: Problem is, that date format is not really sortable. What you could do is break it and use `mktime` to give you a timestamp, which could be sorted with no problem.

Comment: Why would you NOT create it in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format if you're going to sort by it? Sure you can _alter_ it, or do some datetime string parsing & rebuilding in a callback function, but these things are best fixed at the source.

Comment: @Wrikken I am not the source!  I am simply extracting this value off an API call to a SugarCRM call

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a PHP implementation for this technique but technically could just convert your `DateTime` objects to UTC integer values and use a max Heap to heap-sort the `Array`. The newest value simply is the maximum of the max Heap in this case. This should be efficent and fast (with a hint of overkill ;).

Comment: Ah, well, if you can't alter the input, the long way around it is (simply as FK82 describes, although you could sort a normal array instead of using SplHeap, their difference is usually negligible for PHP).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the dates are array values:

```
array_multisort(array_map('strtotime', $array), SORT_DESC, $array);
$yourVar = $array[0];  //or use current() or reset()
```

Comment: Though I would probably use `$stamps = array_map('strtotime', $array)` alone or in the sort and then when you need to display them use date() for whatever format you want using the $stamps array.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a PHP Array where I can make the key's or values be in this
>   format 10/03/2013 01:45pm

If the format of this value is not mandatory then you can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.
In the array you can use strtotime() output which will be in numeric form (for more details follow the link) ***[Now any sorting algorithms will easily short time stamps and you can do all the operation easily and efficiently.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19502842/#)***

> How to convert it to desire format ??
>   Use date function to display dates with following format,

```
echo date("d-m-Y h:i a", strtotime($array[$i]));
```

**Note: If value of array must be in mentioned format (Same as question) then it would be a lengthy process since string comparission and matching is slower then the numeric ones.**